# Python os.path.isdir returns true for dots

Tags: python, windows, shell, os.path

I'm programming my own shell in python. Right now I'm trying to implement the `cd` command to my shell.

The function that performs this command has several variables:

`self.current_dir = "C:\\"` - The default value, it changes depends on the user's input using the cd command

`dir = "..."` - The requested directory that the user types. "..." is an example for an input that causes the problem.

Here is my code:

```
def command_cd(self, dir):
    if os.path.isdir(self.shell.current_dir + dir):
        self.shell.current_dir = self.shell.current_dir + dir + "\\"
```

The problem is that for some strange reason, `os.path.isdir(self.shell.current_dir + dir)` returns `True` when the user types dots (Just like the example inputs for the variables which I gave above).

The problem occurs even if you change the amount of dots (even above 5 dots) and I really have no idea what causes it.

There's obviously no folder named `...` or anything like it.

**If my problem isn't clear enough please comment and I'll edit it**

Comment: `.` refers to the current directory and `..` to the parent directory.

Comment: @wim Oh ok. Do you know when I put 3 dots or 4 dots what does it refer to? Do you think it just mixes up both of them?

Comment: I don't use Windows so I can't answer that.  It could be a bug, some parts of Python aren't very well maintained for Windows.

Comment: `os.path.isdir("...")` returns False on a POSIX machine, as does `ntpath.isdir("...")` when `ntpath` is imported explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is the current directory, `..` is the parent directory, and there no such reference of anything greater than two dots.

But however, the reason for why `os.path.isdir()` returns True is because python registers everything greater than two dots as one dot.

```
import os

print(os.path.abspath(".......") == os.path.abspath("."))
print(os.path.abspath("....") == os.path.abspath("."))

# and that
print(os.path.samefile('......', '.'))
# also prints True
```

They will all print True, since `....`,`.......` and `.` points to the same place.

---

As chepner has pointed out in the comments, this problem doesn’t occur in POSIX systems, whereas it’s caused by `os.stat` mistakenly equates `'....'` with `'.'` (which is not the case, see later edit)

---

**Important Edit:**

Commented by eriksun:

> Windows `os.path.isdir` is implemented by calling `GetFileAttributes`,
>   which calls `NtQueryAttributesFile`. Like all file system functions,
>   first it has to convert the `DOS` path to a native `NT` path. To the
>   kernel `"."` and `".."` are just normal names, so the runtime library
>   first has to normalize the path via the function
>   `RtlGetFullPathName_Ustr`, which also gets used by `os.path.abspath`, so
>   the result is similar. The way it reduces more than two dots and
>   trailing spaces in the final component is a legacy inherited from `DOS`.
>   It's doing its best to emulate an `OS` from the 1980s.

Therefore this problem has nothing to do with python itself, as this problem occurs in Windows cmd as well, `cd c:\.....` or `cd .\....\..` Windows will still let you get away with it, by referencing two than two dots with one dot. As it was inherited from `DOS` to reduce more than two dots to one and remove trailing spaces.

Comment: This is coincidentally relevent, at best. `os.path.isdir` is a wrapper around `os.stat`, which (in POSIX, at least) raises an error on `"..."`; it certainly doesn't silently treat it the same as `".."`.

Comment: My point is, `os.stat` is the call that apparently equates `..` with `...` and longer; Python itself is agnostic.

Comment: Actually, Windows `os.path.isdir` is implemented by calling `GetFileAttributes`, which calls `NtQueryAttributesFile`. Like all file system functions, first it has to convert the DOS path to a native NT path. To the kernel "." and ".." are just normal names, so the runtime library first has to normalize the path via the function `RtlGetFullPathName_Ustr`, which also gets used by `os.path.abspath`, so the result is similar. The way it reduces more than two dots and trailing spaces in the final component is a legacy inherited from DOS. It's doing its best to emulate an OS from the 1980s.

Comment: @eryksun thank you! Your comment is by far I believe the most correct, I hope you don’t mind I quoted it in the answer.

Comment: You could drive yourself nuts over-analyzing the runtime library's DOS emulation. For example, if the working directory is "C:\\", then `os.path.abspath('.../') == 'C:\\...'` yet `os.path.abspath('.../.') == 'C:\\'`. Logically they should be the same, but in the second case there's an initial pass that resolves away the "/.", so the final-component rules get applied to "...", which reduces it to ".", which gets resolved away.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.` in directory structures on modern computers points to the current directory. Similarly, `..` points to the parent directory of the current directory. So, you can navigate up two folders in the directory structure by typing `cd ..\..\` at the windows cmd. It's not a bug, it's a feature! I don't have access to a Windows machine right now, but `cd ...` returns the error `bash: cd: ...: No such file or directory` on my Ubuntu 17.10 laptop. I get the same error with any number of dots greater than 2. If python returns `True` for `...`, that's a bug. I'd add some clause in your cd command that disallows an entry of more than 2 dots, or make 4 dots go up 2 directories, 6 dots 3 directories and so on.

Comment: You ran it in a normal Shell. I'm building my own shell and I'm creating my own `cd` command. It uses `if os.path.isdir(self.shell.current_dir + dir):` to check if the directory exists. The problem is that when it gets an input such as `c:\\....` it returns `True`, I have no clue why...

Comment: I was using my shell as an example of what happens on a standard shell. Obviously you can make yours do whatever you want.

Comment: yeah of course, but the problem is that `if os.path.isdir("c:\\...."):` returns true.. It shouldn't do that as far as I know unless someone has an explanation why it does that?  There's no folder named `...` or `....` etc..